# angular onclick pass values

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-ng-click

This is my AngularJS ng-click function which is not working. I need to get `branch.id` through this function:

```
<tr   data-id="0" ng-model="row1" ng-repeat="branch in details | filter:branchsearch |  limitTo:10" style="border-bottom:1px solid ;">
                        <td style="display: none">{{branch.branch_id}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="getid(branch.branch_id)" class="tablerow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{branch.name}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="getid(branch.branch_id)" class="tablerow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{branch.code}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="getid(branch.branch_id)" class="tablerow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{branch.t_name}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="getid(branch.branch_id)" class="tablerow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{branch.city}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

And there is my Angular function, which is not working:

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
  var adminmodule = angular.module("adminmodule",[]);

    // Branch Controller
    adminmodule.controller("branchcontroller",['$scope','$http','$filter', function ($scope, $http,$filter) {

        branchinfo();
        function branchinfo(){
    // Sending request to branchinfo.php files
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            $scope.pageSize = 10;
            $http.post('http://localhost/sms1/adminAsset/script/branchinfo.php').success(function(data){
    // Stored the returned data into scope
                $scope.details = data;


            });
        }
       
        
        $scope.getid=function (id) {
            alert(id+'haris Done');
        }

        $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
            return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length/$scope.pageSize);
        }


    }]);
```

Comment: `ng-modal`? `ng-model` typo? Or modal plugin?

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: @tymeJV what you are saying ???????

Comment: @MaazKhan47 Now check This

Comment: ng-modal isn't an angularJS extended html property, he is asking if you have a library or something that add that html property or if it was a typo from ng-model

Comment: Where is your `details` variable on which you have populated the table ????

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect this code to do, and what does it do instead? You're iterating on details, but details is not defined anywhere. How could it "work"?

Comment: i update snippet now check it @MaazKhan47

Comment: @JBNizet now check it i update my snippet

Comment: If your table gets created properly or not ?

Comment: @harishaider but you still haven't defined "not working". What do you expect this code to do, and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly why is there post request without any payload to 'get' the `details` data? Then considering what you need just debug to make sure you're getting details data correctly from service, why you're using ng-model on tr? (It's not the input field). Here's a simple plunk which demonstrates what you need:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JLYJNhs4hIBp10WVaIYM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks dear i need your help

Comment: now i want to get this branchId in javascript code how can i get it